# Grunt hangs on uglify

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am trying to minify a little angular script, but for some reason uglify just hangs indefinitely.  JSHint runs fine and completes if I add it into the task list, and then it hangs on uglify.

Here is my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        // make node configuration available for use
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // configure uglify
        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false
            },
            my_target: {
                dist: {'dist/test.min.js': ['src/test.js']}
            }
        },

        // configure JSHint
        jshint: {
            app: ['src/*.js']
        }

    });

    // load pluginsng
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


    // default
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'uglify']);
    grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['uglify']);
};
```

Here are the versions I am using:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

I ran `grunt -v` and after jshint finishes it outputs this forever:

```
Running "uglify" task

Running "uglify" task

Running "uglify" task
```

It doesn't seem to care what file I give it either, so it seems to be hitting some issue before it gets to reading my file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're redefining the uglify task to run itself in your last line, replacing grunt-contrib-uglify:

```
grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['uglify']);
```

That's why your grunt is looping endlessly.
Just give it a **different** name:

```
grunt.registerTask('compress', ['uglify']);
```

Comment: Thanks...I knew it was something silly.  Don't know why I didn't catch that.